# Galileo - servo motor moves only in one direction and it doesn't turn back

Tags: servo, arduino-galileo

I have an Intel Galileo (1st gen) and a servo motor (Tower Pro SG90).

My problem: my servo moves only in one direction and it doesn't turn back.
I want to perform a movement from 0° to 90° and then from 90° to 0° again.

At the moment, I have just tried the official arduino snippet for servo motor that should perform a similar movement. But, as said before, the servo doesn't turn back.

**Here the code**

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created 

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
} 


void loop() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```

Obviously I have made the attachments like on [arduino tutorial](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/sweep).

Every help will be greatly appreciated! :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you testing this? Do you manually push the servo back to the 0° position? What happens if you swap the 2 for loops? Or increase the delay to something like `delay(300)`? Very odd problem you have there.